# How to handle an undefined parameter?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, undefined

I am developing an angular application. As part of it, i want to handle a case when certain paramter is undefined.

my code

```
  myImage() {
    console.log('test')
    console.log(typeof(this.ahuObservables.on_off_status))
    this.myValue = this.myObservables.status
    console.log(typeof(this.myValue))
    if (this.myValue  == null)
    {
      console.log('undefined')
      this.ahuValue = 0
    }
    else{
    // do something
   }
```

```
 getDataRealTime()
  {
    console.log('Making a request')
    this.SocketService.socket_connection()
      .subscribe(
        (data1: any) => {
          console.log(data1)
          let data11 = JSON.parse(data1)
          this.myObservables = new My_Observables()
          this.myObservables.status = data11['status']
          console.log('variables parsed') 
        }
      )


  }
```

`this.myObservables.status` is assigned in an api call. So when my api is not working i want my `myValue` variable to be 0. I have tried checking null, undefined but i am not able to assign a default value if myObservables.status is undefined.My second console.log is also not priniting anything in console. can some one help me with it?

Thanks.

Comment: so `if (this.myValue === undefined)` does not work for an undefined value???

Comment: Did you try `====`??

Comment: `if (this.myValue === undefined)` is not working, i was expecting it to work ,but its not

Comment: what is even `this.myObservable.status`?

Comment: How are these code snippets related? when is each called? what is `My_Observables`? This is surely not a [mcve], please provide one.

Answer (score 0):

`if (!this.myValue || this.myValue==null)` this will check undefined and null also.

```
myImage() {
    console.log('test')
    this.myValue = this.myObservables.status
    console.log(typeof(this.myValue))
    if (!this.myValue || this.myValue==null)
    {
      console.log('undefined')
      this.ahuValue = 0
    }
    else{
    // do something
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `this.myValue` has a **falsy** value by adding `if(!this.myValue)`, then the if statement will be executed only if this.myValue has a value of 0, empty string, undefined or null.

```
myImage() {
        console.log('test')
        console.log(typeof(this.ahuObservables.on_off_status))
        this.myValue = this.myObservables.status
        console.log(typeof(this.myValue))
        if (!this.myValue)
        {
// this part of the code will be executed if this.myValue is 0, empty string, undefined or null
          console.log('undefined')
          this.ahuValue = 0
        }
        else{
        // do something
       }
```